# Laravel where 2 columns like keywords

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a 'Person' table with the following 2 columns, 'First_Name' & 'Last_Name'
Is there a way to get a filtered list of Person using Laravel Eloquent by Joining the 2 columns and testing if **the concatenation is like the keywords**.

something like

```
Persone::where('First_Name' + 'Last_Name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
```

Comment: Try `Person::whereRaw('CONCAT(First_Name, Last_Name) LIKE %?%', [$keywords])->get()`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @Laisender comment

```
Person::whereRaw('CONCAT(First_Name, Last_Name) LIKE %?%', [$keywords])->get();
```

which works fine, yet caused some SQL errors when I added other 'where'

This line solved it

```
where(DB::raw('CONCAT(First_Name, Last_Name)'), 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%')->get();
```